# Multiply a column data in gnuplot script in TexStudio

Tags: latex, gnuplot, tex

I have some data mydata.dat like this:

```
    #   Basis   DMR-RE TMR
    Basicmath   3.30109E-06 7.65853E-06 4.06034E-06
    blowfish    2.24812E-06 4.72105E-06 2.72022E-06
    crc 2.25266E-06 6.98326E-06 2.92846E-06
```

and I have following gnuplot script myplot.tex to plot bargraph.

```
 \begin{gnuplot}[terminal=cairolatex, terminaloptions =  {size 8cm, 7cm}] 

 reset
 red = "#FF0000"; green = "#00FF00"; blue = "#0000FF"; skyblue =      "#87CEEB";
 set style data histogram
 set style histogram cluster gap 1
 set style fill solid
 set boxwidth 0.9
 set xtics format "" rotate by 90 right nomirror
 set grid ytics
 set key horizontal
 unset border
 set title ""
 set ylabel "Time" offset 2.5,0
 set xlabel "Apps"
 plot "../gnudata/hist_exe.dat" using 2 : xtics (1) title "Basis"      linecolor rgb red, \
 '' using 3 title "DMR-RE" linecolor rgb blue, \
 '' using 4 title "TMR" linecolor rgb green

 \end{gnuplot}
```

And this script is called in main Latex file as:

```
    \begin{figure}[t!]
    \input{../myplot.tex}
    \end{figure}
```

This works fine. 
Now I want to multiply each column by a constant e.g. 1000000. I tired using ($2 * 1000000) but it gives me errors. I think there is a problem using a $ inside gnuplot script inside TexStudio.
I also tried 
(\$2 * 1000000) but gave me errors.
Can anyone please help me.
Regards

Comment: It worked when i removed xtics(1) as follows: plot "../gnudata/hist_exe.dat" using 2 title "Basis"      linecolor rgb red,.... But could place x labels now.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `xticlabels` instead of `xtics`? Also, "gives me errors" is not very informative -- what is the error you are getting?